# Adding Menu items to Task tray application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application that on startup should not open a form, but sit in the task tray, when right clicking on the icon in task tray it should bring up the menu items.

At this point I get it to bring up 2 menu items, and when clicking on the menu items it opens the associated form or exits as it should.

I want to now add a third menu item, but for some reason it does not display when I run the application, right click, only the first two I added are options

my App.Context looks like this

```
  public class AppContext : ApplicationContext
{
    NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    Integration configWindow = new Integration();
    receiving_Help helpWindow = new receiving_Help();
    public AppContext()
    {
        MenuItem configMentuItem = new MenuItem("RFID_Integration_Test", new EventHandler(ShowConfig));
        MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(Exit));
        MenuItem HelpMenuItem = new MenuItem("Help", new EventHandler(showHelp));//This item does not appear in the menu as an option



        NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Asterisk;
        notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { configMentuItem, exitMenuItem });
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

    }
    void ShowConfig(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If we are already showing the form, focus on it
        if (configWindow .Visible)
        {
            configWindow .Activate();
        }
        else
        {
           configWindow .ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    void showHelp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If we are already showing the form, focus on it
        if (helpWindow.Visible)
        {
            helpWindow.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            helpWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove icon before we exit
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        Application.Exit();

    }
```

I have tried adding a new menu item called test and linking it to the existing exit event handler just to see if that would work, but it didn't even show test as an option.

I can update the names of my existing menu items, so its not a refresh issue

Comment: What is `ApplicationContext`? I though I know winforms a bit. Perhaps you are missing some tags?

Comment: Every WinForms application has one ApplicationContext intance, and it holds an instance to the form object that will serve as the main form. It serves as an application start and termination notification link between the main form in your application and the UI thread. I am using it to instead of starting the default Form1 inProgram.cs to load the tweaked ApplicationContext

Comment: [I see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), thanks. As to your problem: you simply forgot to add `HelpMenuItem` to array when constructing `ContextMenu `.

Comment: Yes, I saw that now too, 
thanks your post beat me by a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out I was not paying attention...

I created the menu Item,  butI was not adding it to the NotifyIcon context menu..

```
notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] { configMentuItem, exitMenuItem, HelpMenuItem });
```